# setTimeout is not showing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I try to do a pop up and its suposed to work like this:
After 3 seconds it will show the button to close but while you wait 3 seconds , there's going to be a countdown.
My problem is that is showing no text

```js
var n = 3;

function popup() {
  set.setTimeout(function() {
    getElementById('bro').style.visibility = visible;
  }, 3000);
  
  while (n > 0) {
    set.setTimeout(function() {
      n--;
    }, 1000);
    n.toString()
    getElementById('texto').innerHTML = n;
  }
}

function bro() {
  getElementById('bro').style.display = "none";
  getElementById('texto').style.display = "none";
  getElementsByName('block').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#bro {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#texto {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body onload="popup()">
  <p id="texto" color="red">3</p>
  <button id="bro" onclick="bro()">close</button>
  <aside name="block"></aside>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you need document.getElementById instead of just getElementById

Comment: also having a global function with the same name as the element is going to cause problems.

Comment: What is `set`? Unless it's a reference to the `window` object (which itself would be *very* odd) then your `setTimeout()` calls are going to cause syntax errors.

Comment: You expect the n-- inside of the timeout to change the text where you call it outside of the timeout??? It does not work like that. The reference to the variable does not update the innerHTML..... Also makes no sense why you would have a while loop with the setTimeout running. Looks like you are going to have a browser lock up.

Comment: I would suggest looking at some more js tutorials before you try this, as mentioned above, what is set.setTimeout()? Also you aren't referencing the dom at all, document.querySelector('#textto');
        document.querySelector('#bro')
        document.querySelector('.block') and you are mixing up visibility with display. I would say start from the top

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm typing with my mobile phone and I don't have access to a tool for writing the complete code easily, but look at this mistakes in your code:

1. You must Add `document.` before any `getElementById` in your code.
2. You must wrap `visible` between " ":  `document.getElementById('bro').style.visibility = "visible"`;
3. What is `set` (in `set.setTimeout`)? remove it from before of  `setTimeout()`.
4. What is `n.toString()`?. you must assign it, no using it directly: `.innerHTML=n.toString()`
5. Put `while` in `setInterval()`
6. You have used `visibility` in `popup` function and `display` in another place (for change visibility of `bro`). Use one of them in your code (`css` and `js` and `html`);
7. Use `document.querySelector('[name="block"]').style.display = "none";` for hiding the `block` elem.
   8- Change `z-index` of `#texto` to 3.

---

**Updated part:**

Now, you can test the result here. **this is your code itself** that its problems have been solved:

```css
#bro {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#texto {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 20pt;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
 <body onload='popup()'>
  <p id="texto" color="red">3</p>
  <button id="bro" onclick="bro()">close</button>
  <aside name="block"></aside>
  <script>
    var n = 3;
    function popup() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('bro').style.visibility="visible";
      }, 3000);

      var t2=setInterval(function() {
        debugger
        if(n--==0) clearInterval(t2);
        else document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML=n+"";
      }, 1000);

    }

    function bro() {
      document.getElementById('bro').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById('texto').style.display = "none";
      document.querySelector('[name="block"]').style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have added a part with a full example which have solved your solution's problem.  you can check it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing visibility and display. Your timeout function is setting visibility to visible but the display value is still set to none. Change all the display "none" to visibility "hidden".

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues with it.

- What is the property `set`?
- Your setTimeout will be executed almost everytime.
- What you need to do is to use a whole second setTimeout and check the current loop, if matches `n`, then you display your close button.

I've refactored your code a little and should look more or less like this:

```js
let n = 3;
let c = 0; // counter

const hideAll = () => { 
  hide(document.getElementById('texto'));
  hide(document.getElementById('bro'));
  hide(document.getElementById('block'));
}

const show = (el) => el.classList.remove('hidden');
const hide = (el) => el.classList.add('hidden');

const showPopup = () => { 
  show(document.getElementById('block'));
  startCountingDown();
}

const startCountingDown = () => setTimeout( countdown,  1000 );

const countdown = () => { 
  if(c < n) { 
    c++;
    let texto = document.getElementById('texto');
    texto.innerHTML = c.toString();
    show(texto);
    startCountingDown();
  } else { 
    show(document.getElementById('bro'));
  }
}

showPopup();
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
#bro {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#texto {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  z-index: 3;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<p id="texto" class="hidden">1</p>
<button id="bro" onclick="hideAll()" class="hidden">close</button>
<aside name="block" id="block" class="hidden"></aside>
```

I've changed the sizes of your elements in order to fit properly within this page. 
I have also created a .hidden class, which you can add or remove to show and hide your elements. I believe this is a good approach for you to start from.

I hope it helps